# n.sort is not a function error

Tags: angularjs, rest, syncfusion

I'm using Angular JS with syncfusion and schedule component. I have a rest api made in asp.net core and I made a client for it in angularjs. I'm trying to get all appointments for the schedule component, however when assigning them to the scope variable that binds to schedule it comes up with an error. I tried googling this error however I haven't found anything useful and I'm not very proficient in angular or javascript yet.

When I make an array with appointment objects manually it works, but when I passed it from my appointments service it doesn't.

This is the error:

```
angular.js:14525 TypeError: n.sort is not a function
at Object._sortAppById (http://cdn.syncfusion.com/15.1.0.41/js/web/ej.web.all.min.js:10:3533264)
at Object._dataProcessing (http://cdn.syncfusion.com/15.1.0.41/js/web/ej.web.all.min.js:10:3536745)
at Object._bindAppointmentsData (http://cdn.syncfusion.com/15.1.0.41/js/web/ej.web.all.min.js:10:3529006)
at Object._init (http://cdn.syncfusion.com/15.1.0.41/js/web/ej.web.all.min.js:10:3298250)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://cdn.syncfusion.com/15.1.0.41/js/web/ej.web.all.min.js:10:21539)
at r.fn.init.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as ejSchedule] (http://cdn.syncfusion.com/15.1.0.41/js/web/ej.web.all.min.js:10:22796)
at Object.post (http://cdn.syncfusion.com/15.1.0.41/js/common/ej.widget.angular.min.js:10:9542)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:17:3
at ra (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:85:35)
at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:70:226) "<ej-schedule id="Schedule1" e-width="100%" e-height="525px" e-currentview="currentView" e-currentdate="Date" e-appointmentsettings-datasource="appointments" e-appointmentsettings-id="id" e-appointmentsettings-subject="name" e-appointmentsettings-starttime="startTime" e-appointmentsettings-endtime="endTime" e-appointmentsettings-description="comments" e-appointmentsettings-allday="isAllDay" e-appointmentsettings-recurrence="isRecurrence" e-appointmentsettings-recurrencerule="recurrenceRule" e-directive-name="ejSchedule" class="e-schedule e-js e-scheduleouter e-tooltip" tabindex="1" style="width: 100%; height: 525px;" role="presentation">"
```

This is my function to get them from service in controller:`

```
appointmentsService.getAppointments().then(function (results) {
        $scope.appointments = results.data;
        console.log($scope.appointments);
    });
```

and then this is my service:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module("myApp");

    app.factory('appointmentsService', ['$http', function($http) {

        var serviceBase = 'http://localhost:63185/';
        var appointmentsServiceFactory = {};

        var _getAppointments = function () {
             return $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/appointments').then(function (results) {
                 return results;
             });
        };

        appointmentsServiceFactory.getAppointments = _getAppointments;

        return appointmentsServiceFactory;

    }]);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly include the below code example in your web api service project controller file.

```
public List<DefaultSchedule> GetData()
    {

        List<DefaultSchedule> datas = _context.DefaultSchedule.Take(500).ToList();
        return datas;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public List<DefaultSchedule> Batch([FromBody] EditParams param)
    {
        if (param.action == "insert" || (param.action == "batch" && (param.added.Count > 0))) // this block of code will execute while inserting the appointments
        {
            DefaultSchedule appoint = new DefaultSchedule();
            object result;
            if (param.action == "insert")
            {
                var value = param.value;
                foreach (var fieldName in value.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    var newName = fieldName.ToString().Split(null);
                    if (newName[1] == "Id") result = (_context.DefaultSchedule.ToList().Count > 0 ? _context.DefaultSchedule.ToList().Max(p => p.Id) : 1) + 1;
                    else if (newName[1] == "StartTime" || newName[1] == "EndTime") result = Convert.ToDateTime(fieldName.GetValue(value));
                    else result = fieldName.GetValue(value);
                    fieldName.SetValue(appoint, result);
                }
                _context.DefaultSchedule.Add(appoint);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in param.added.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i }))
                {
                    var value = item.Value;
                    foreach (var fieldName in value.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        var newName = fieldName.ToString().Split(null);
                        if (newName[1] == "Id") result = (_context.DefaultSchedule.ToList().Count > 0 ? _context.DefaultSchedule.ToList().Max(p => p.Id) : 1) + 1 + item.Index;
                        else if (newName[1] == "StartTime" || newName[1] == "EndTime") result = Convert.ToDateTime(fieldName.GetValue(value));
                        else result = fieldName.GetValue(value);
                        fieldName.SetValue(appoint, result);
                    }
                    _context.DefaultSchedule.Add(appoint);
                }
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        if ((param.action == "remove") || (param.action == "batch" && (param.deleted.Count > 0))) // this block of code will execute while removing the appointment
        {
            if (param.action == "remove")
            {
                DefaultSchedule app = _context.DefaultSchedule.Where(c => c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(param.key)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (app != null) _context.DefaultSchedule.Remove(app);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var a in param.deleted)
                {
                    var app = _context.DefaultSchedule.ToList().Where(c => c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(a.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (app != null) _context.DefaultSchedule.Remove(app);
                }
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        if (param.action == "update" || (param.action == "batch" && (param.changed.Count > 0))) // this block of code will execute while updating the appointment
        {
            var value = param.action == "update" ? param.value : param.changed[0];
            var filterData = _context.DefaultSchedule.Where(c => c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(value.Id));
            if (filterData.Count() > 0)
            {
                DefaultSchedule appoint = _context.DefaultSchedule.Single(A => A.Id == Convert.ToInt32(value.Id));
                appoint.StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value.StartTime);
                appoint.EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value.EndTime);
                appoint.Subject = value.Subject;
                appoint.Recurrence = value.Recurrence;
                appoint.AllDay = value.AllDay;
                appoint.RecurrenceRule = value.RecurrenceRule;
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        List<DefaultSchedule> datas = _context.DefaultSchedule.Take(500).ToList();
        return datas;
    }
```

Kindly include the below code example in your angularJS sample front end page.

```
<body>
<div class="content-container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cols-sample-area">
            <div ng-controller="ScheduleCtrl">
                <ej-schedule id="Schedule1" e-width="100%" e-height="525px" e-currentview="currentview" e-currentdate="setDate"
                    e-appointmentsettings-datasource="appointments" 
                    e-appointmentsettings-id="Id" 
                    e-appointmentsettings-subject="Subject" 
                    e-appointmentsettings-starttime="StartTime"
                    e-appointmentsettings-endtime="EndTime" 
                    e-appointmentsettings-description="Description" 
                    e-appointmentsettings-allday="AllDay" 
                    e-appointmentsettings-recurrence="Recurrence" 
                    e-appointmentsettings-recurrencerule="RecurrenceRule"
                    e-appointmentsettings-applyTimeOffset="false">
                </ej-schedule>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module('ScheduleApp', ['ejangular']).controller('ScheduleCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.appointments =  ej.DataManager({
            // get the required appointments from Web API service
            url: "http://localhost:15154/api/Schedule/GetData",
            crudUrl: "http://localhost:15154/api/Schedule/Batch",
            adaptor: new ej.UrlAdaptor()
        });
        $scope.setDate = new Date(2014, 11, 5);
        $scope.currentview = "week";
    });
</script>
```

Run the service project first and keep it on the run state. Then change the above code example service URL in the front end html page.